# Glass.Mapper.MapperException Message: Failed to map field

Tags: glass-mapper, upgrade

While integrating castle windsor into sitecore 8.2 project with glass.mapper, we are getting below error when it was trying to map Internal Link field type. Is there any specific version of glass mapper that resolves this issue? relevant glass issue # 227 - https://github.com/mikeedwards83/Glass.Mapper/issues/227

**Configuration:**
[image: Sitecore showconfig initialize section]

**Exception:**

> Exception: Glass.Mapper.MapperException Message: Failed to map
>   property WidgetTitle on
>   UNWomen.SC.Common.Model.Communications.sitecore.templates.UN_Women.Communications.Items.Generic_Highlight
>   Source: Glass.Mapper    at
>   Glass.Mapper.Configuration.AbstractTypeConfiguration.MapPropertiesToObject(Object
>   obj, IAbstractService service, AbstractTypeCreationContext context) in
>   c:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\8567e2ba106d3992\Source\Glass.Mapper\Configuration\AbstractTypeConfiguration.cs:line
>   138
>
> Nested Exception
>
> Exception: Glass.Mapper.MapperException Message: Failed to map to
>   property 'WidgetTitle' on type
>   'UNWomen.SC.Common.Model.Communications.sitecore.templates.UN_Women.Communications.Items.Generic_Highlight'
>   Source: Glass.Mapper    at
>   Glass.Mapper.AbstractDataMapper.MapCmsToProperty(AbstractDataMappingContext
>   mappingContext) in
>   c:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\8567e2ba106d3992\Source\Glass.Mapper\AbstractDataMapper.cs:line
>   68    at
>   Glass.Mapper.Configuration.AbstractTypeConfiguration.MapPropertiesToObject(Object
>   obj, IAbstractService service, AbstractTypeCreationContext context) in
>   c:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\8567e2ba106d3992\Source\Glass.Mapper\Configuration\AbstractTypeConfiguration.cs:line
>   121
>
> Nested Exception
>
> Exception: Glass.Mapper.MapperException Message: Failed to map to
>   property 'WidgetTitle' on type
>   'UNWomen.SC.Common.Model.Communications.sitecore.templates.UN_Women.Communications.Items.Generic_Highlight'
>   Source: Glass.Mapper    at
>   Glass.Mapper.AbstractDataMapper.MapCmsToProperty(AbstractDataMappingContext
>   mappingContext) in
>   c:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\8567e2ba106d3992\Source\Glass.Mapper\AbstractDataMapper.cs:line
>   68    at
>   Glass.Mapper.Configuration.AbstractTypeConfiguration.MapPropertiesToObject(Object
>   obj, IAbstractService service, AbstractTypeCreationContext context) in
>   c:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\8567e2ba106d3992\Source\Glass.Mapper\Configuration\AbstractTypeConfiguration.cs:line
>   121
>
> Nested Exception
>
> Exception: Glass.Mapper.MapperException Message: Failed to map field
>   {DD6452B1-3612-462B-92D3-534212C67172} with value
>   /sitecore/content/Settings/Common
>   Text/Communications/Widgets/Highlights Source: Glass.Mapper.Sc    at
>   Glass.Mapper.Sc.DataMappers.AbstractSitecoreFieldMapper.GetField(Field
>   field, SitecoreFieldConfiguration config, SitecoreDataMappingContext
>   context) in
>   c:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\8567e2ba106d3992\Source\Glass.Mapper.Sc\DataMappers\AbstractSitecoreFieldMapper.cs:line
>   147    at
>   Glass.Mapper.AbstractDataMapper.MapCmsToProperty(AbstractDataMappingContext
>   mappingContext) in
>   c:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\8567e2ba106d3992\Source\Glass.Mapper\AbstractDataMapper.cs:line
>   60
>
> Nested Exception
>
> Exception: System.NullReferenceException Message: Configuration
>   Resolver pipeline did not return a type. Has the type been loaded by
>   Glass.Mapper. Type: System.Object Source: Glass.Mapper    at
>   Glass.Mapper.AbstractService.InstantiateObject(AbstractTypeCreationContext
>   abstractTypeCreationContext) in
>   c:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\8567e2ba106d3992\Source\Glass.Mapper\AbstractService.cs:line
>   144    at Glass.Mapper.Sc.SitecoreService.CreateType(Type type, Item
>   item, Boolean isLazy, Boolean inferType, Dictionary`2 parameters,
>   Object[] constructorParameters) in
>   c:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\8567e2ba106d3992\Source\Glass.Mapper.Sc\SitecoreService.cs:line
>   506    at
>   Glass.Mapper.Sc.DataMappers.SitecoreFieldTypeMapper.GetFieldValue(String
>   fieldValue, SitecoreFieldConfiguration config,
>   SitecoreDataMappingContext context) in
>   c:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\8567e2ba106d3992\Source\Glass.Mapper.Sc\DataMappers\SitecoreFieldTypeMapper.cs:line
>   64    at
>   Glass.Mapper.Sc.DataMappers.AbstractSitecoreFieldMapper.GetField(Field
>   field, SitecoreFieldConfiguration config, SitecoreDataMappingContext
>   context) in
>   c:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\8567e2ba106d3992\Source\Glass.Mapper.Sc\DataMappers\AbstractSitecoreFieldMapper.cs:line
>   134

Answer (score 2):

This issue has been mentioned here: http://www.glass.lu/Mapper/Sc/Documentation/CommonQuestionsAndProblems/SystemObjectError. When [T4 templates](http://www.glass.lu/Mapper/Sc/Tutorials/Tutorial24) are used to generate glass based models, it generated model properties of type "object" for every "internal link" field type. And glass.mapper.sc has stopped mapping properties of type 'object' as part of a fix for issue# 85 in glass mapper github repo.

So, one can start using Glass.Mapper.Sc.Fields.Link type to corresponding to sitecore fields of type "internal link". Then, Any version of glass.mapper would work.